# How do I know Slack bot's user_id?

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I'm making a slack bot (A) that responses to a message from another slack bot (incoming-webhook) (B).
I'd like to know the user_id of B so that its message will be a trigger for A, where I have some problem getting it.

I tried users.list method (https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=blabla) but the B didn't appear in a result.
Do you have an idea about what method to take to know the user_id of B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incoming webhooks appear as apps, not as bot users on Slack. So you won't find a bot user ID in the user list as you would for normal bot users.

Apps have a bot ID, but unfortunately there is no official API method to get the list of bots / apps in a workspace. But if you have control over a workspace and can generate a legacy token you can use the unofficial API method [bots.list](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/bots.list.md).

There also is the official [bots.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/bots.info) method, if you already have the bot ID and just want to know which app it belongs to.

To create a legacy token for your workspace make sure you are logged in and then go to [this page](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens).